# best practices for using sqlite for a database queue

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, transactions

I am using an sqlite database for a producer-consumer queue.

One or more producers INSERT one row at a time with a new autoincremented primary key.

There is one consumer (implemented in java, uses the [sqlite-jdbc](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) library) and I want it to read a batch of rows and delete them. It seems like I need transactions to do this but trying to use SQLite with transactions seems to not work right. Am I overthinking this?

If I do end up needing transactions, what's the right way to do this in Java?

```
 Connection conn;
 // assign here

 boolean success = false;
 try {
    // do stuff
    success = true;
 }
 finally
 {
    if (success)
       conn.commit();
    else
       conn.rollback();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, with SQLite there are explicit (not implicit!) transactions. So you need something like "START TRANSACTION" of course, it could be that your Java binding has this incorporated -- but good bindings don't.

So you might want to add the necessary transaction start (there might be a specialiced method in your binding).

Comment: that seems to do it; when I execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "END TRANSACTION" SQL statements instead of using JDBC's commit/rollback functions, it seems to work properly.

Comment: Hi Jason, at least you need BEGIN TRANSACTION (in some libs there are specialiced methods to do this). END TRANSACTION should be in result the same like COMMIT.

Comment: As Juergen noted, the begin transaction method can be something like `db.beginTransaction();`

Answer (score 5):

See [this trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) for an introduction on transaction handling with Java JDBC.

As for your use case, I think you should use transactions, especially if the consumer is complex. The tricky part is always to decide when a row has been consumed and when it should be considered again. For example, if you have an error before the consumer can actually do its job, you'll want a rollback. But if the row contains illegal data (like a text in a number field), then the rollback will turn into an infinite loop.